# Mobile-friendly D3.js bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a force bubble chart with D3.js. I am almost done, the only thing is that when I am simulating on a mobile, the positions of the bubbles are not adjusting to the size of the screen (I don't see any bubble). When I look at examples, it seems to display correctly on mobiles.

What part of the code in D3.js is changing the mobile display ?

You can visualize my project from this link (some things don't work like the background picture but the bubbles are there. We see them in tablet and desktop mode but not on cellphone mode). You can access the github page by following the same path : https://rawgit.com/aubertsigouin/canAi/master/index.html

Comment: Could we see your code please?

Comment: Here is my JS file

Comment: Here is the rawgit of the project, you can access the whole project by going to github with the same path : https://rawgit.com/aubertsigouin/canAi/master/index.html . Some things don't work on rawgit like the background picture and stuff but you can see how I am able to show bubbles in Desktop and Tablet mode but not in cellphone mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is your svg bigger than the screen?

You can set the size of the svg based on the window size.

```
let svg = d3.select('#teck-stack-svg');
svg.attr('width', window.innerWidth);
svg.attr('height', window.innerHeight);
```